# Can you re-wire an EU house with UK sockets?

Tags: wiring, receptacle

We've recently bought a house in Bulgaria needing renovating, can we rewire the house with UK sockets or even as spurs off the ring main as we intend on taking all our possessions with us, and furthermore feel that this may be a selling point in the future . Thanks Iain

Comment: Don't see why not from the point-of-view of physics - but are you asking from a legislative perspective?

Comment: Ask your local electrician about what the code requires, likely the answer is no. Also to whom should installing an inherently insecure ring mains or virtually unusable sockets be a selling point?

Comment: http://whatplug.info/from/uk/to/bulgaria

Comment: When your fridge will die, will you plan to go to UK to bring back a new one with the UK plug to fit your house ?

Comment: Thanks Stefandz, I think my enquiry was more based on whether it would be acceptable and safe, not having too deep an understanding of electrics, I understand about the difference between radials and ring circuits, and how lights are wired , cookers and showers/boilers  needing different gauge cables and mcbs etc, I was intending to chase out where necessary and lay cables for the electrician to connect to sockets and the consumer unit, to reduce labour costs, I gather that the UK sockets are among the safest type to use of the dozen or so that are used worldwide. Thanks

Comment: Thanks dim, good point, having reviewed this, my question regarding the possibility of 2 radials per room is a better one perhaps,

Comment: The opposite seems allowed - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schuko currently says "Some [Irish or British?] hotels provide a Schuko outlet alongside BS 1363 outlets for the convenience of visitors from the Continent."

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why not so long as you install everything to the local regulations and ensure proper fusing, etc. Ring Mains are a uniquely British circuit so you'd be looking at radial circuits so you would need to check the fusing (circuit breakers) are an appropriate rating for your sockets. Also bear in mind that if you have no local sockets, buying a new appliance with a Bulgarian plug on it is going to be frustrating.

You can fit whatever sockets you like to an installation so long as you do so safely in accordance with the local electrical regulations. That doesn't mean you can just replace all the sockets without checking how they are connected and protected. If you're not competent to follow the appropriate regulations, hire an electrician to do it.

Done properly with decent quality sockets (e.g. MK) this is going to be a lot safer than using those shonky travel adaptors etc.

Comment: Thank you Ian, so what about the possibility oh having a radial with double EU sockets and a radial with double UK sockets in the same room, with one situated above the other

Comment: So far as I can see on principle it should be fine to simply parallel UK BS1363 sockets with the Bulgarian Schuko sockets since the circuits should be 16A radials, which is also the standard radial fusing in the UK. The UK sockets will in fact be a bit safer than the Shukos since they are inherently polarised and the plugs are fused down to 13A max. I am a (former) electrician so am qualified to talk about this stuff btw. However, I have no experience with Bulgarian regulations. You'd need to see if there is anything else in their regs to conform to. Which I presume are written in Bulgarian.

Comment: Thank you Ian, the thought of UK sockets came to me recently, further research showed them to be safer and better for a number of reasons, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Last question Ian, is it 4mm cable  if I'm planning socket radials ? :) or at least for today :)

Comment: Cable sizing depends on the load, length of run, earth loop impedance etc. Us sparks actually have to learn a load of complicated calculations to ensure the correct cable size, which would be in the Bulgarian regs. Contrary to popular belief, it's not just 1 mm for lights, 2.5 for rings, etc... :) In the UK it's at least 2.5, might be 4, might even be 6 on a long run. It depends on the type of cable being used as well. If you're going to have an electrician connect it, ask him what cable to put in. Pay particular attention to earthing regulations. If you Earth is too small, circuit breakers...

Comment: ...won't trip fast enough, or might not trip at all. Which is very dangerous. Also consider that if you do have (or have to have) separate radials for the UK sockets, that's a lot of new cable running/chasing and probably a new, or additional, consumer unit too for the extra circuits.

Comment: Many thanks again Ian, I have understood all that you have said, I'll plan and measure everything when I ask the electrician, and will let him advise me what cables and sockets I need to get, I don't mind the extra work load nor having to get an additional consumer unit, but i also understand how their regs may be different to ours, and that this grand scheme might not  be acceptable there. Again I thank you for replying and helping me toward the two houses we recently bought in BG. Iain